# Can checkstype use regex in "files from package" filter

Tags: regex, filtering, checkstyle

The code generated by xjc.exe to create classes from an XML Schema has lots of Checkstyle warnings. I can use a Checkstyle "files from package" filter in a project to ignore the source generated by xjc.exe but I have to select each package individually and I use JAXB classes quite a bit.

I use a naming convention for the generated code where the package name contains .JAXB. and ends with .classes

Is there a way to specify a generic filter in Checkstyle so that packages generated by xjc.exe are ignored?

- Can I do it globally in the the Checkstyle configuration, so it is applied to all projects in the workspace?
- Can it be done in the project's .checkstyle file?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define a `suppressions.xml` in your project like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="[\\/]JAXB[\\/].+?[\\/]classes[\\/][A-Z]" checks="." />
</suppressions>
```

The `[A-Z]` at the end of the `files` regex assumes that your classes start with an uppercase letter. This way, `classes` only matches as the last package name element ([regex explanation](http://regex101.com/r/lM3uT5)).

Then, in your checkstyle configuration, you enable the *SuppressionFilter* like this:

```
...snip...
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${workspace_loc}/Project/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
...snip...
```